# How can I find out which library is including libcmt?

Tags: windows, linker, msvcrt, visual-studio-2010, libcmtd

I'm trying to link a Windows executable that depends on a several static libraries (some of which I have built, some of which I have not).  When I do the link, I get a flock of errors like:

```
LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: _unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
```

which is the classic /MD vs. /MT problem (whether the C runtime is statically or dynamically linked).  I tried the easy solution first, adding the linker flags

```
/nodefaultlib:libcmt /nodefaultlib:libcpmt
```

but that just gave different errors:

```
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::_Locinfo::~_Locinfo(void)" (??1_Locinfo@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in gtest.lib(gtest-all.cc.obj)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.cc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int std::locale::id::_Id_cnt" (?_Id_cnt@id@locale@std@@0HA)
```

I've gone through the libraries I'm building, and as far as I can tell I'm building them all /MD.  I say "as far as I can tell" because some of them are third-party libraries that come with their own makefiles so I don't have complete control over the build process..

I don't think "depends" works on libraries (only EXEs and DLLs), is there a tool that would let me look at the various libraries I'm linking in, and see which one is bringing in libcmt when I want to be using msvcrt instead?

Comment: The premise that you can't control this with boost is just false.  It even uses a different name for the .lib file, all you can do is pick the wrong name.  Not for gtest, typical Google problem, you really do have to rebuild it.  /MD is the universal "always works" setting, use it consistently.

Comment: Sorry, mentioning boost was a bad idea.  There are several third-party libraries involved, boost is only one.  I am selecting what I believe to be the correct boost libraries, but (1) I might be doing it wrong, and (2) there are other third-party libraries that aren't as straight-forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same problem and I used dumpbin ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z66yd3h6.aspx ) with /DIRECTIVES options on the libs. It will show a number of /DEFAULTLIB sections, each one is another lib that your lib try to use. Dumpbin needs to run from the Visual Studio command promt.

```
dumpbin /DIRECTIVES liblua52.lib
```

I had 100+ libs with all the solution configurations and platforms so I made a python 2.7 script (crtdisplay.py) to do it for me. It can be found on my bitbucket repository at https://bitbucket.org/vimarina/ctrlcv/src/57b7ddca15b5c7fefddcf20ffcea0633223a4bd6/crtdisplay . Put it in the root directory of your libs. Not much error checking in that code so do not be surprised if it fails :). I used Visual Studio 2010 so might fail on other versions of Visual Studio.

```
 crtdisplay.py > info.txt
```

Comment: I had trouble just scouting around using dumpbin, as /DIRECTIVES didn't show anything interesting.  It turns out that some of the libs didn't have any at all.  Those are not the problem!  Scanning through all the libs until I found some with directives listed and eventually found conflicting ones.